# How to get the Response in ReactiveElasticsearchClient

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-webflux, spring-data-elasticsearch

Search template request is:

GET test/_search/template { "id": "histogram-template", "params": { "from": "now-1d", "to": "now" } }

```
SearchTemplateRequest request = new SearchTemplateRequest();
request.setRequest(new SearchRequest("testindex"));//index
request.setScriptType(ScriptType.STORED);
request.setScript("test");
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>(); //
params.put("from", "now-1d");
params.put("to", "now");
request.setScriptParams(params);
Flux<SearchHit> response = client.searchTemplate(request);
```

How I get the response? need help in spring boot reactive.

How can I get the data in to the JSON format? May i using the correct API method searchTemplate? Please suggest with real example.

Comment: SearchTemplateRequest request = new SearchTemplateRequest();
    request.setRequest(new SearchRequest("testindex"));//index
    request.setScriptType(ScriptType.STORED);
    request.setScript("test");
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>(); //
    params.put("from", "now-1d");
    params.put("to", "now");
    request.setScriptParams(params);
    Flux<SearchHit> response = client.searchTemplate(request);

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, use the [edit] link in your question.